# connect to jira with python

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I've got code as follows to connect jira api:

```
from jira import JIRA
jira_server = {'server': JIRA_URL}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_server, basic_auth=(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD))
```

Every time I'm trying to connect I get:

AttributeError: 'SSLError' object has no attribute 'headers'

No idea why, could anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `options` argument expects a dictionary with `headers` as show in [this example](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html#headers) of the documentation.

It looks like you need to use the `server` argument. This seems to be the way to initialize the `JIRA` object.

```
from jira import JIRA
jira_server = {'server': JIRA_URL}
jira = JIRA(server=jira_server, basic_auth=(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD))
```

Comment: nope, no change, the same error

Comment: I've tried also:     jira_options = {
   'server': jira_server_name,
   'verify': 'path/to/root/certificate',
} and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way. Jira, don't know why, doesn't read my cert.
To solve this issue:

1. import certifi and with certifi.where() command find location of your cert file
2. open browser with jira url
3. click lock icon next to jira url>connection is save>certificate is valid>certification_path
4. on each cert on list click show_certificate>details>copy_to_file>choose option x.509...base64 and save to file
   5 copy each of above exported certificates to the file from certifi.where.
   6 for authentication I used `jira = JIRA(server=jira_server, basic_auth=(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD))` and works :)